# Proportion of time a sum of Gaussians is above 0

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-walk

I am stuck with the following problem.
For any $k\geq 1$, let $N_k$ be a standard Gaussian, and $X_k:=\sum_{j=1}^kN_j$.
I would need to prove the following:
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb{I}\{X_{2^i}\geq 0\}=1/2$$
or in plain english, the proportion of times $X$ is greater than 0 (along the sequence $2^i$) goes to 1/2 almost surely.
I feel like I should use somewhere a kind of symmetry of the "random walk" somewhere, but I do not really know how...

Thank you very much in advance for trying this problem!

Comment: Since $X_k=-X_k$, can you relate $\Bbb I\{X_k > 0\}$ to $\Bbb I\{X_k <
 0\}$ in two different ways?

Comment: I do not really understand the hint. I guess a first way is just $\mathbb I \{X_k>0\}=1-\mathbb I \{X_k<0\}$ (ignoring the case $X_k=0$). Since $X_k=-X_k$ only in distribution, how could I use it to deduce anything about {>0} directly?

Comment: A thought:  The PDF of a sum of random variables is the convolution of the PDFs of the random variables.  The convolution of two Gaussians with 0 mean is a Gaussian with zero mean.  Therefore, the PDF of your random variable $X_k$ is a gaussian with 0 mean.  Since it’s symmetric about 0, the probability of getting a positive number is 1/2.